# IFrame content not displaying full height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a responsive IFrame on my primary site and cannot get the content to display 100% height. [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4nOg.jpg). The image inside should be a rectangle shape. The width displays fine, but the IFrame either compresses the image to a shorter length, or maybe it's only displaying a smaller square portion of the height? Please advise what I am doing wrong, or can do, so the content displays 100% of the width and 100% of the height of the IFRAME

Thank you in advance!! :)

Here is a link to the IFrame page: https://www.pravacanamats.com/custom-yoga-mat-designer/

Also here is the current code html and CSS being used:

```
    <div class="iframe-container iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto;">
 <iframe src="https://www.beehoneyom.com/product/yoga-mat/"> <iframe src= marginheight="1" height="1"> 
<p style="font-size: 110%;"><em><strong>IFRAME: </strong> There is iframe content being displayed here but your browser version does not support iframes.</em>Please update your browser to its most recent version and try again.</p> </iframe> 
</div>
<iframe width="100%" height="768" src="https://www.beehoneyom.com/product/yoga-mat/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Here is the CSS code as well:          .iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350 {
padding: 25px 25px 70% 25px; /* padding-bottom = h/w as a % */
}

.iframe-container iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 50;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
/* put following styles (necessary for overflow and
scrolling handling) in div container around iframe
because not stable in CSS
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow: auto; */
}

Comment: your site takes a very long time to load!

Comment: if you see here, it is messed up.



>     <iframe width="100%" height="768">
>     </iframe> src="https://www.beehoneyom.com/product/yoga-mat/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: As @techLove says, you are limiting your iframe height to 768 px. Change it to height="100%".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/02m1x2e6/ this works but you should work on the load time - it takes ages.. people will bounce off your site.. is it a problem that the add text/images etc are smaller? You don't have control over that from the iframe end as it's part of the other website..

Comment: @techlove. Thank you. I tried that first, hence the set pixel height of the container itself. If I change the setting to 100% versus the 768, it only adds a scroll bar but the display size of the image is the same?

Comment: @ Rachel, yes the load times are almost inevitable because the end image requires that many pixels (on the page being iframed) so the customers can see their exact resolution of final image creations. There will be a disclaimer to clients that the process may take a few moments.

Comment: @RobynPrice I don't think that'll prevent bounces. There are things that you can do to reduce load times. A few moments is a bit of an understatement!  you can cache your images so that people returning to the site won't have to wait as long for it to load etc. Google how to reduce load time

Comment: @RobynPrice i just ran pagespeednsights on the page. it scores 0/100! That's a bit (a lot!) worrying...  even your index page only scores 30/100..You could at least optimise your images. Tinypng.com is good for compressing images

Comment: https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/speed-up-your-website/

Comment: @RobynPrice please consider accepting my answer: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (or just hover beside answer and click the checkbox. You gain 2 rep by accepting the answer)

Answer (score 2):

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/02m1x2e6/) of some improved, corrected html and css. However, your site takes a very long time to load still and there ARE simple things you can do about it. [Minify your own HTML](http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/), [javscript](https://javascript-minifier.com/) and [css](http://cssminifier.com/), the files on your server.

Read how to [leverage browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) (this makes a big difference) and a bonus would be if you [optimised css delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) and [js delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

I see that you enabled compression since i posted the slow-load comment but it still ranks at 0/100 on both desktop and mobile on [PageSpeedinsights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). This is a very handy tool for testing the speed of your website. Helps gauge bounce rate too.

Hope this helps!

```css
#makemat {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;
}

.iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350 {
  padding: 25px 25px 70% 25px;
  /* padding-bottom = h/w as a % */
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="makemat" class="iframe-container iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350">
  <iframe src="https://www.beehoneyom.com/product/yoga-mat/" marginheight="1" height="1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>  </iframe>
  <p style="font-size: 110%;"><em><strong>IFRAME: </strong> There is iframe content being displayed here but your browser version does not support iframes.</em>Please update your browser to its most recent version and try again.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: btw when you are responding to a comment, the user's name who you are responding to should pop up when you type the '@' symbol and the first letter. Don't leave a gap, or it doesn't go to the user's inbox. It was by chance i saw your last response (I came back to the question) - so I would be @RachelGallen for example  (no gap between first name and surname or after the @ symbol)

Answer (score 1):

```
iframe {
         height: 100vh;
         width: 100%;
       }
```

**[Working Fiddel is here](https://jsfiddle.net/YoJey_Thilipan/6naLm0yc/9/)**